# What is the bronze "shield" currency?

Tags: injustice-2-mobile

In Injustice 2 on mobile you earn different currencies for completing challenges, missions etc. One of the main ones you seem to get from the daily achievements is a bronze shield kind of thing with a up arrow in it.

[image]

What is this for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bronze shield currency is EXP. You can easily see this when you claim the achievement your EXP bar jumps up quite a bit.